# Nginx Ingress is trying to use deleted load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I deployed an [ArgoCD](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) using its [official chart](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-helm/tree/master/charts/argo-cd). I decided to expose it using an Ingress which is described below:

```yaml
ingress:
  enabled: true
  ingressClassName: nginx
  hosts:
    - argocd.domain.com
```

It worked once nicely, but for running some tests I deleted the Ingress object, which didn't delete the AWS load balancer it was using. Now, every time I create a new Ingress resource it redirects to this deleted load balancer.

How can I reset which load balances he's trying to use or at least force an update? I don't want to stop the Nginx ingress controller but I feel this is going to be the solution.

Comment: not getting your point, which didn't delete the AWS load balancer it was using. Now, every time I create a new Ingress resource it redirects to this deleted load balancer. you might want to change the ingress class if you are running the two ingress controller of ngixn or so